# Xamarin forms, find corresponding checkbox to label in listview and check it when clicked on label

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, styling

I have this `ListView`:

```
                    <ListView x:Name="listview_items"
                              Margin="0,10,0,0"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                              HasUnevenRows="True">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid>

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Text="{Binding itemText}"
                                               FontSize="22"
                                               Margin="0,5,0,5"
                                               FontFamily="Font_11"
                                               TextColor="#424242">

                                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Label>

                                        <CheckBox
                                            Color="#97A5AD"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}"
                                            CheckedChanged="chk_accept_shipment_CheckedChanged"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Scale="1"
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                          
                                            x:Uid="{Binding itemID}"
                                            x:Name="{Binding itemID}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListView>
```

As you can see, it contains a `Label` and a `CheckBox`, when the user checks the checkbox, I gets checked. But now, I have a gesture recognizer attached to the label. When the user taps the label, I want to find out which checkbox is next to the label and also check it (as if the user actually clicked the checkbox).

How do I find the corresponding checkbox to the label next to it?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally bind the `IsChecked` property to my `ViewModel`.

Example:

```xml
            <StackLayout
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectAllCategoriesCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsAllCategoriesSelected}" />

                <Label Text="Select All Categories" />
            </StackLayout>
```

The binded property can be something like :

```cs
    private bool _isAllCategoriesSelected;
        public bool IsAllCategoriesSelected
        {
            get => _isAllCategoriesSelected;
            set
            {
                _isAllCategoriesSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsAllCategoriesSelected);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to pass CommandParameter in tap so you can get that in TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped In that you will get which Item table click so according that you have to check check box

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding itemID}" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
</Label.GestureRecognizers>


async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var d = (TappedEventArgs)e;
            var data = d.Parameter as int;//yor itemID type

        }
```

Comment: This returns null as a paratemer. even when it wouldnt. How would I access the checkbox on data ?

Comment: Pass CommandParameter="{Binding .}" so you can access in that.